# Design pattern for this?

Tags: design-patterns

I have an array of objects. I want to pass it through a few steps that will modify each object in the array. These steps are independent of each other, and may not all be used in every case. Looking for a design pattern that might describe this behavior.

Thanks

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You may be looking for the [Visitor](http://www.dofactory.com/Patterns/PatternVisitor.aspx) pattern.

Answer (score 2):

I would use the `Composite` and `Command` patterns.  Each one of your discrete operations would be a `Command` instance, implemented in the `execute` method that the pattern specifies.  I would use `Composite` because you want to do more than 1 command. In effect you would have a "composite command" that you apply to each element of the array.

Answer (score 2):

It seems to me you are describing a pipeline.

One writeup on this pattern is http://stevenatkinson.wordpress.com/2009/03/02/pipeline-design-pattern/.

Answer (score 1):

Performing an operation on each object of collection -> Iterator or Visitor

Encapsulating a series of operations -> Command

Answer (score 1):

Visitor is a good choice for performing the operation.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you should take a look at the "chain of responsibility" pattern. The goal of this pattern is very close (if not equals to) what you express. A chain of responisibility is composed by several commonds which can handle a request. In your case, the request is your array; each command can modify the array; after handling the array, each command calls the next command in the chain of responsiblity.

This pattern is very clearly explained in the "design pattern" by the GoF.

Answer (score 0):

I see the visitor pattern more suited for this purpose even thought I personally don't like to use as it sometimes violates object encapsulation as it can access all the visited class implementation details.

Answer (score 0):

All day, this is a [Chain of Responsibility](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chain-of-responsibility_pattern)